# Is this the correct interpretation of the regression output (panel data)?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, inference, panel-data

I've got some sample data which looks like this:

[image]

For example, firm 1 took 3 weeks to innovate following X policy change, firm 2 took 6 weeks to innovate following X policy change, etc.

Since this is panel data, I ran a regression (fixed effects) where the dependent variable is Innovate and the independent variable is Week. I got this output:

[image]

How do I interpret the coefficient for Week? I'm interested in knowing how likely it is that a firm will innovate when I increase the number of Weeks since policy change X by one unit. However, I'm not sure if my output is telling me that increasing the number of weeks by 1 increases the probability that the firm will innovate by 17.6% given that there aren't any logs.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify, what do you mean when you say *given that there aren’t any logs*?

Comment: @ThomasBilach in the past when I've done some regression analysis, when the independent variable (Y) is a log, it's possible to say that an increase in one unit of a dependent variable (X) leads to a % increase in Y. So, to interpret the coefficient in this case, if the Y variable was a log, I suspected that I could say something along the lines of 'an increase in the week by 1 leads to a 17.6% increase in Innovate'. However, software doesn't let me transform Innovate to Log_Innovate before the regression, I suppose due to the structure of the data. Therefore, I'm unsure what to do.

Comment: What software are you using? The model only includes your weekly time index?

Comment: I also assume this is *not* a fixed effects logit model. Correct?

Comment: @ThomasBilach thanks for your explanation below, it helped to clarify things! The software I used was gretl and it only includes the weekly time index. The coefficient was estimated with a fixed effects model, but I didn't specify logit. Is it fine to estimate a LPM with panel data using the fixed effects model to reach the interpretations you pointed out? My understanding was that OLS is applied to non-panel data when estimating a LPM, assuming innovate is linearly related to the time.

Comment: @ThomasBilach also, if innovate isn't linearly related to time, is this where I'd need to look at a fixed effects logit model?

Comment: You can use a linear probability model (LPM). It will ease the interpretability of the model coefficients. One of the reasons to avoid an LPM is because it will produce predicted values *outside of* the 0 to 1 range. Try reviewing this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389203/to-what-extent-does-a-linear-probability-model-lpm-violate-the-gauss-markov-as) for more information.

Comment: Oh great, thank you. So implementing the LPM by running an OLS regression with innovate as the dependent variable and week as the independent is fine to do with panel data? Also, given the limitations of LPM, I know we can use logit/probit models - but is there a special way to use logit/probit with panel data specifically? @ThomasBilach

Comment: Yes. You can use it. Just make sure you're aware of their limitations in this context. As for a specific use case, I do not know of any applications in gretl. I work primarily in R.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted another question related to this in a new thread which overlaps with this but lays out the problem a bit more clearly. Would appreciate your input if possible: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465672/using-linear-probability-model-with-panel-data-what-to-do-when-r-squared-is-lo @ThomasBilach

Comment: No problem! Instead of focusing on the interpretability of the coefficients, you should frame your question in terms of the appropriate methodology for your particular data (i.e., time to some observed event).

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You're estimating a linear probability model (LPM) using panel data.

> [I]n the past when I've done some regression analysis, when the independent variable (Y) is a log, it's possible to say that an increase in one unit of a dependent variable (X) leads to a % increase in Y.

Not quite. You are confusing $X$ and $Y$. I'm sure this was a minor oversight on your part. If you logged $Y$, you would multiply the coefficient by 100 (e.g., $[\beta\cdot100]$) to obtain the percentage change in $Y$ given a one unit increase in $X$.

> [S]oftware doesn't let me transform Innovate to Log_Innovate before the regression, I suppose due to the structure of the data.

This is not surprising; $\text{log}_{n}(0)$ is *undefined*.

> How do I interpret the coefficient for Week?

The variable "Week" enters the model as a *continuous* linear time index. In your setting, the time since the new policy was introduced increases the chance that *Innovate* = 1. This may not be reasonable. As more and more time passes, it might be less likely that a firm will innovate. A question to consider is whether the probability of "innovating" is *linearly* related to the time a firm is under observation. Moreover, your data *within a firm* is clearly truncated; in other words, the time series ends once a firm innovates. This is one of several potential substantive considerations. As for the interpretation, a weekly increment increases the *probability* a firm will innovate by .176. If you are partial to *percentages*, then you could interpret this as the probability of firm innovation being 17.6 percentage points *higher* each weekly increment post-policy adoption.

Given the structure of your data, I would investigate the benefits of a [survival model](https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7.pdf).